# Parting gift for departing manager for which I didn't contribute hasn't arrived, and I'm the one supposed to give it to him

Tags: people-management, gifts

I've been working in a multinational company for a few months now and I've noticed that, at least in the European branch, every time something "big" comes up (like a wedding or someone leaving), everyone is asked to contribute for a gift.

The way it usually goes is:

1. a top manager asks all distribution lists via email if they'd want to contribute
2. they select a person (the "gifter") that works together with the the person who's getting the gift
3. people send money to the gifter
4. the gifter chooses something that conforms to the amount sent and gives it on behalf of everyone who contributed

Now I don't like this system and I always choose not to participate, but I've found myself in a predicament.

- My boss is leaving the company **and moving to another country** at the end of the week and the gifting process has gone as usual, but this time my colleague decided to split the money (it was a few hundred €), and buy several things. Almost all of them came and they gave them to him, but the last one (an Amazon Echo) is taking longer.
- After that my boss went on vacation to start packing and moving things, and because my colleagues would all be going on vacation by the time he comes back to finish up some stuff, then my colleague told my boss that I'd be giving him the rest.
- And then he told me that the package didn't arrive, and he went on vacation.

Just for clarification, the way it was supposed to happen is:

My colleague gets the package -> He gives it to me -> I give it to my boss when he comes back

But the first part never completed so I'm stuck.

- So now I'm expected to give a gift I don't have, to which I didn't contribute to, to my direct boss who is leaving on friday, and he's been told I'd give it to him.

What can I do?

This is related to vacation schedule and it's a bit convoluted so I'm putting a rough calendar here:

| 4 weeks ago | 3 weeks ago | 2 weeks ago | a week ago | this week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gifts come, boss goes on vacation, colleague tells him I'll be giving him the rest | Colleague tells me the package is not coming | Everyone else goes on vacation, it's only me in the office | Boss comes back (It's me and him in the office) | Boss will be definitely going on friday, and I still don't have the package |

Comment: So what's wrong with showing him/her the Amazon update on the scheduled arrival and delay?
Perhaps you can forward the gift to his new address (when it arrives)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I'm not the one who's dealing with the package, I was only supposed to hold the package once it arrived and wait till the boss came back then give it to him.

Comment: And what is the update (expected arrival) from whoever is in charge of dealing with the package? They could either change (destination address) or if it's too late for that, wait and then send it to the boss's new address. I don't see how you could be blamed for an Amazon delivery that was delayed for whatever reason.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is no update. They are on vacation.

Comment: "i don't like this system and I always choose not to participate" - why not? Participation is optional and someone receives a present. What's not to like?

Comment: Not all questions that are set in the workplace are workplace questions.

Comment: @Corey If you think this question should be closed then go ahead and vote for it, but I'd like to know why you think that way.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't been set up for this? To find out, just ask for the shipping documents, as @ypercubeᵀᴹ proposed.

Comment: @DavidDPG you could start by telling us why you think this is a workplace question. You might as well be asking how to keep your pants up, but at work.

Comment: @Corey Well because a colleague of mine kept a gift for a boss of mine, that i was meant to give to him. Granted it's not something that ONLY happens in work related environments, but i can assure you that my work was all i was thinking of when i posted this. Also you haven't answered me. To me this is a communication problem that poses a threat to my work position. I find that largely on topic.  Can you please specify why is it not, and stop with the half baked comments?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just explain it like you did here. You didn't do anything wrong.

There's no need to beat around the bush or anything. Just tell your boss "hey, I'm sorry Boss, I'm not able to give you the gift right now as it isn't here yet. We'll figure it out when it's here and make sure to send it to your new address". There's no need to mention whether or not you've contributed to the gift or not.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, but then again he's expecting me to give him the gift by the end of the week and, to be honest, I'm a bit worried my colleague is just going to keep it for himself. I guess I'll accept your answer and ask another question if that happens.

Comment: To head off that possibility, include your colleague in what you say. "Hey Boss, as you know X is getting your gifts but he's on holiday, so I can't give you the last bit. We'll figure it out when he's back and make sure to send it on."

Comment: @DavidDPG: If your colleague keeps it for himself... so what. What do you care? You have no liability in any of this. If your boss doesn't end up getting some of the gifts... tough luck. If your boss is that bothered, then let him worry about chasing it up. Both him and your colleague can fight it out together, it's not your concern.

Comment: Good answer, I would add that if it was going to be a surprise, then towards the ends, say Thursday, tell him what it is so he can 1. Get the good feeling that "They got me this." and 2.  Let you know if you should bother shipping it. Honestly if this guy is a manager in a MNC, he's not going to get bent out of shape and send the mob after you for a $50 item.

Comment: And depending on where you're locating, there are extenuating circumstances due to the flooding two weeks ago - there is still a lot of backlog and delayed packages of things that ship from and through Germany

Comment: @musefan i was just worried about the possibility of being blamed for something i didn't even want to participate to begin with, but i guess you're right, i'm overthinking this too much.

Comment: If you did not wrong, there is no need to say sorry. Just stating the facts is enough

Comment: Tell your boss in person, @DavidDPG, (just to be nice), then follow up with an email to the effect of, "Hey boss, sorry the last part of your gift didn't get here in time. Bob handled the ordering and he's on vacation, so when he gets back, we'll get it sorted out & get it to you". Then, most importantly, **copy Bob on the email**. This way everyone knows what's going on, and if Bob decides to keep it (as you seem to be concerned), it's on _him_ not on you.